# how to rename sections in latex

Tags: latex

How can i give another name to the main sections of a scientific paper in Latex? So instead of 'References' i wanna write a different title, instead of 'Abstract' another, and so on.

Regards

Comment: For anyone who may be reading this in the future, there is an Area51 proposal for these kinds of questions: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148/tex-latex-and-friends?referrer=5z6F4dAmVScN5QfMOt5KEg2 (disclaimer: URL includes my referral link)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Redefine any of the following commands:

- Abstract: `\abstractname`
- Appendix: `\appendixname`
- Bibliography: `\bibname`
- Chapter: `\chaptername`
- Contents: `\contentsname`
- Index: `\indexname`
- List of Figures: `\listfigurename`
- List of Tables: `\listtablename`
- Part: `\partname`
- References: `\refname`

So, for example,

```
\renewcommand\refname{My References}
```

The list comes from *The LaTeX Companion*, 2nd edition, page 34.

Comment: Huh, strange. Maybe try `\providecommand` instead of `\renewcommand` and see if that works.

Comment: This worked for me BUT, only if I put `\renewcommand` after `\begin{document}`--not in the preamble.

Comment: This does not seem to work for sections. Could someone add how to do this for an article section or should this be a separate question?

Comment: @Constantin that would be a separate question, but it's probably already asked somewhere on [tex.SE].

Comment: In bibliography case, be careful that other bibliography packages like `babel` can supersede this command.

Answer (score 6):

For references `\bibname` is defined in the `book` class, but not in the `article` class. The latter is using `\refname`.

Answer (score 3):

thanks! helped me a lot.

Just to help other fellas, it did not work for me before `\begin{document}`

I did it just before \part as below:

```
\renewcommand\partname{Capítulo}
\part{\textit{Conjuntura regulatória}}
\chapter{\large MATRIZ ENERGÉTICA BRASILEIRA}
```

worked as a charm.